# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Is there anyone can suggest from the eloquent relationship that I have based on the screenshot and model setup? 
[image]

Model setup:

```
class Leaves extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'leaves';

    protected $fillable = [
        'leave_type',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}

class LeaveType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'leave_type';

    protected $fillable = ['type_name'];
}

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function leave()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Leaves');
    }

}
```

Currently I only able to get the leaves detail but need to retrieve the leave_type's type_name based on

```
$user = User::oldest('name')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
     $user->leave()-get();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `Leave` model you would have

```
function type() {
    return $this->hasOne(App\LeaveType);
}
```

in your LeaveType you should reciprocate

```
function leave() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\LeaveType);
}
```

and in your controller:

```
$user = User::oldest('name')->with('leave', 'leave.type')->get();
dd($user->leave->type);
```

Comment: also note the lack of `()` after `->leave` and `->type` when getting the properties. `leave()` would return a query builder so you can do `$user->leave()->create($leave);`

Comment: I seemed to have problem for the function type()
is there anything wrong with my foreign key reference? from the attachment, the leave_type from Leaves table is foreign reference to leave_type table

Comment: I missed that, sorry, the default for laravel is `model_name_id`. In your case that would be `leave_type_id`, but you can override that. the syntax is `return $this->hasOne('App\Model_Name', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

Answer (score 0):

Leaves model:

```
class Leaves extends Model {
   protected $table = 'leaves';

    protected $fillable = [
        'leave_type',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function LeaveType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LeaveType');
    }

}
```

LeavesType model:

```
class LeaveType extends Model {
    protected $table = 'leave_type';

    protected $fillable = ['type_name'];
    public function Leaves()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Leaves');
    }
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function Leaves()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Leaves');
    }

}
```